# Get html links from html page in Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to get some html links (that can contain UTF-8 characters like russian aso) and to store them in Strings in my java application.
As the html pages I'm receiving contains a lot of errors, I used HtmlCleaner Which works really well btw).

With those clean html pages I'm now facing a problem :
I tried to gather those strings in an XML file with an XSL stylesheet but when I want to read the file with dom4j SAXReader fails because some special chars (like & for parameters in a link) are still present.

So my question is : what is the easiest way to get those html links and store them in Strings without having to parse them 36 times.

The HTML page contains a table. Here is one row:

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>title</td>
<td>3:48</td>
<td align="center"><a href="http://..." target="_blank" rel="nofollow"  ><img src="images/fisher_listen_icon1.gif" width="18" height="18" border=0></a></td>
<td align="center"><a target=_blank rel="nofollow" onclick="loadornot()" href="http://..."><img border=0 width="18" height="18" src="images/d.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
```

And I would like to store this row in an object (each td will be an attribute).

Thanks ;)

Comment: Why don't you just use regex and extract the href= attribute?

Comment: Using regular expressions you makes it hard to skip comments, texts surrounded by special tags like `<code>` or `CDATA`.

Answer (score 0):

replace the ampersands while you are parsing HTML using code like `url.replace("&", "&amp;")`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with html the easiest way IMO would be to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

For example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

for (Element link : links) {
       System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Swing or HTMLParser like in this example: [example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0639.html)

then you can get href like

```
if (tag == Tag.A) {
  String address = (String) attribute.getAttribute(Attribute.HREF);
  list.add(address);
}
```